# Error on npm build in Azure build pipeline with Angular project

Tags: angular, azure, azure-pipelines

Im having an error running build pipeline in Azure. here is the error:

[image: Error]
The build fails after this and I cant seem to figure this one out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could solve,

Setting "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan, it work just fine. 